# How to convert SQL into Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use the flask. As a result, I need to convert the following SQL query into flasksqlalchemy one.
Is it possible to replicate the query bellow in flasksqlalchemy? What would be the equivalent?
Thank you much

```sql
SELECT table1,
       table2,
       table3,
       table4,
       table5,
       table6
FROM Data
       INNER JOIN Table2 on Table3.Column1 = Table2.Column2
       INNER JOIN Table5 on Table4.Column1 = Table3.Column2
       INNER JOIN Table1 on Table5.Column1 = Table1.Column2
WHERE Table2.Column2 = 'FOO';
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Hopefully the answer will prevent someone else from wasting too much time with this:

```
query = db.session.query(table1,
       table2,
       table3,
       table4,
       table5,
       table6)
    query = query \
        .join(Table2, (Table3.Column1 == Table2.Column2)) \
        .join(Table5, (Table4.Column1 == Table3.Column2)) \
        .join(Table1, (Table5.Column1 == Table1.Column2))

    result = query \
        .filter(Table2.Column2 = 'FOO').all()
```